Is it possible to install Laravel Jetstream with Typescript?
Is it possible to install Laravel Jetstream with Typescript instead of Javascript when you are installing it with Inertia/Vue?
I saw that they have it with Breeze but I can't find it for Jetstream.
If it is not possible to achieve it during the installation steps, is there a clean way to revert the js files in the project to ts files? I doubt it is a good idea though, there are 40 of them in the codebase.
Thank you.
